# Including the same ComboBox in each row in a ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm designing a WPF application in XAML. I have a ListView containing a GridView; each list item corresponds to a bus stop. Each bus stop belongs to a "zone", the list of which is fetched dynamically when my application runs. For each row in the list I'd like to display a ComboBox that is populated with the list of zones, and which the user can use to sort each stop into the appropriate zone.

I understand how I could do this if the zone list were static: just define the ComboBox in the GridViewColumn.CellTemplate and populate the ComboBox right in the XAML. Since the list is dynamic, though, will I need to use data binding to hook it up, or is there something simpler that will work?

Comment: So all your ComboBoxes will have the same items?

Comment: @Dilshod Yes... once I obtain the list of items those items will be the same for each bus stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should have a `public ObservableCollection<Zone> Zones{get;set;}` and you can bind your comboBoxes to Zones property.

I hope this helps.